# How to attribute values from matrix pointers in a function

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm creating a code which transposes a matrix through a function. When I run this code however, it prints the original matrix, but it closes without printing the transposed matrix. I'm almost certain the problem is with the attribution inside the transpose function, but I can't understand it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Here I create a function to transpose the matrix
//I receive a pointer to a double matrix
void transpose(double *matrix[][5], int size)
{
    //I create a second matrix
    double transposed[size][5];
    //I transpose the original matrix into the transposed matrix
    for (int i=0; i<=size-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=4; j++)
        {
            transposed[j][i] = *matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    //I attribute the values from the transposed matrix to the original matrix
    for (int i=0; i<=size-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=4; j++)
        {
            *matrix[i][j] = transposed[i][j];
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    //Here I create a matrix and ask for the user to type its values
    double matrix[5][5];
    for (int i=0; i<=4; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=4; j++)
        {
            printf("Position [%d][%d]", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%lf", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //I use the function
    //I print the matrix after using the function
    transpose(matrix, 5);
    printf("Transposed:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<=4; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=4; j++)
        {
            printf("%lf   ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler warning about "levels of indirection" should have tipped you off. The function should be

```
void transpose(double matrix[][5], int size)
```

and the other `*` stars should be removed too.

```
transposed[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
...
matrix[i][j] = transposed[i][j];
```

---

Aside: your loop control limits are not idiomatic. This `i<=size-1;` is better as `i<size;` (and can be wrong).

Where you have hard coded the limit such as `j<=4` it is not immediately apparent that this is actually `5-1` and if you had used `j<5` that would be more obvious that it is the same `5` as in the array dimension.

Should you decide to replace that dimension with a `#define` or a `const int` value, you'll have to hunt down the `4`s and well as the `5`s.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand why it worked (how it is pointing to the matrix) if I'm not putting the *. Besides, this is strange cause it's the second time today that my compiller hasn't warned me about something strange in the code. Can I have turned off something important or something alike?

Comment: An array passed to a function decays to a pointer. It is never the array itself that it passed, although the syntax looks like that.

Comment: It depends on the compiler / IDE. I use MSVC which produced the warning. If you are using gcc then the option `-Wall` should do it.